# HeatMap visualization (ListDensityPlot)

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, visualization, scripting

I have two sets of values, `e1 = {0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3,0.35,0.4,0.45,0.5,0.55,0.6,0.65,0.7,0.75,0.8}` and `e2 = {0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3,0.35,0.4,0.45,0.5,0.55,0.6,0.65,0.7,0.75,0.8}`. For each combination of values, I have a separate CSV file. For example, `e1_0.15-e2_0.15.csv, e1_0.15-e2_0.2.csv, ...` etc. Thus I have `196 distinct CSV files`. Further, each of these files has 3 columns and 9 rows, where the first row is the header (Wt_bfit, Mut1_bfit, Mut2_bfit). Also, in some files the first row in one column or two columns is empty, i.e., has no value ( examples are attached as screenshots), but this happens essentially in the first row after the header. I intend to create a `ListDensityPlot` from the last two columns; Mut1_bfit and Mut2_bfit, and for each row separately. Thus I want the values of `e1 on the x-axis` and those of `e2 on the y-axis` to create a `14x14` grid and fill in the values from each row of the corresponding CSV files. Thus I must have `8 figures`. I created the heatmap, however, I am not sure whether the values and colors are assigned to the combination of parameters correctly. Secondly, I want if a value is not available in the CSV file, there should be a different color spot at that particular place, and thirdly, I want to fix a uniform range for the legend bar (minimum value to the maximum value in the data frame), however, it keeps varying for each row's plot. My approach is as under:
Please note that the variable `interval` is the maximum time for the dynamics and `column` is the second or third column from the CSV file. Any suggestion or comment is appreciated.

[image: An example of the CSV file data]
[image: second example]

```
Clear["Global`*"];

imgSize = 450;
imagePadding = {{100, 20}, {85, 20}};
lblstyle = Directive[Black, 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue"];

interval = 6000;
column = 2;
directoryPath = "here is path to all CSV files"

e1Values = Range[0.15, 0.8, 0.05];
e2Values = Range[0.15, 0.8, 0.05]

fileNames = 
  Flatten[Outer[
    StringJoin[directoryPath, "e1_", ToString[#1], "-e2_", 
      ToString[#2], ".csv"] &, e1Values, e2Values, 1]];

data = Import[#, "CSV"] & /@ fileNames;

mut1Data = Table[data[[i, 2 ;;, column]], {i, Length[data]}];

transposedData = Transpose[mut1Data];

overallMin = Min[Select[Flatten[transposedData], NumericQ@# &]];
overallMax = Max[Select[Flatten[transposedData], NumericQ@# &]];


heatmaps = 
  Table[ListDensityPlot[
    Transpose@Partition[transposedData[[i]], Length[e1Values]], 
    DataRange -> {{0.15, 0.8}, {0.15, 0.8}}, 
    PlotLabel -> Style[StringJoin["Compartment ", ToString[i]], 20], 
    LabelStyle -> lblstyle, 
    FrameLabel -> {Style[
       "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(1\)]\)", 20], 
      Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(2\)]\)", 20]}, 
    FrameTicks -> {{e1Values, None}, {Reversede2Values, 
       None}}(*Automatic*), 
    ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, White, Red}, #] &), 
    PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[BarLegend[{(Blend[{Blue, White, Red}, #] &), {-0.033, 
         0.033}}, LegendMarkerSize -> 400], Right], Mesh -> False, 
    PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> imgSize], {i, 
    Length[transposedData]}];

grid = Grid[Partition[heatmaps, 4], Spacings -> {0.5, 0.5}]
Export["grid_heatmap_Mut" <> ToString[column - 1] <> "_" <> 
   ToString[interval] <> ".pdf", grid];
```